# Windows 7 Access Violation

Tags: c#, c++, boost, clr

I am writing a C# application that contains a set of GUIs and uses a C++ CLR wrapper dll. The structure is like this:

C# APP -> C++/CLR DLL -> C++ Native Code static library

I can run the app on my development machine (Windows server 2012) and also on a Windows 10 machine. However on Windows 7 when the application tries to load the DLL it crashes with an access violation exception. I can't figure out what in my DLL is causing the crash and why it's only on windows 7. Everything is compiled in 64 bit. Also I believe it might have to do with the boost libraries I use in my C++ static library but I'm not sure why it would only throw an exception in windows 7.

## Edit:

So I have been doing more debugging and the issue happens at LoadLibrary("myDll.dll") and not at any initialization. It still is only happening on windows 7 and not windows 10.

Comment: and whats the violation address? is it 0x00000 or some where near like 0x000008 if so you got a null ref

Comment: @Steve How would I tell? The exception thrown in C# doesn’t say.

Comment: The only thing on top of my head is to put a bunch try catch in c++ code for the initialization part. If that doesn't work then WinDB might have to kick in

Comment: @Steve the issue occurs just when the dll is loaded not whenever I am calling any initialization because the debugger never even breaks at the initialization of my DLL class

Comment: Time for some low level stuff then. Google GetLastError and see if you can get some information out of the exception. My best guess is null ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with boost threads. My static lib uses boost libraries that internally use boost threads. To fix the issue I added a command line define `/DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK` to both my static library and C++/cli wrapper dll. This means that I had to include the dll files for boost thread, chrono, and system along with my own dll. Why this only happens on Windows 7 and not 10 I am not sure, but I would guess it has to do with the kernel on Windows 7 and how it handles the way boost threads work.